# Exclude storeview in hreflang generation

Tags: magento-1.8, hreflang

I use this code for the href language in my `head.phtml`

```
<?php $website = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getStores();
foreach ( $website as $store) {
    $lang = $store->getConfig('general/locale/code');
    echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $store->getCurrentUrl() . '" hreflang="' . $store->getCode() . '"/>' . "\n";
}?>
```

Which gives for all my languages the right storeview. Like:

```
<link rel=alternate href="http://www.mystore.nl/lifestyle.html?___store=nl&amp;___from_store=nl" hreflang=nl />
<link rel=alternate href="http://www.mystore.co.uk/lifestyle.html?___store=en&amp;___from_store=nl" hreflang=en />
etc....
```

Only for our app we created an extra storeview `mobile`. But this isn't a language and Google gives error's over this.

How can i excluded the storeview `mobile` in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon you can simply replace the following line:

```
echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $store->getCurrentUrl() . '" hreflang="' . $store->getCode() . '"/>' . "\n";
```

With that one (see the condition before the `hreflang` attribute):

```
if("mobile" != $store->getCode()) 
{
    echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $store->getCurrentUrl() . '" hreflang="' . $store->getCode() . '"/>' . "\n";
}
```

Comment: This doens't work. The output is now: `<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.mystore.nl/junior.html?___store=nl&amp;___from_store=nl" <?php if("mobile" != $store->getCode()): ?>hreflang="nl"<?php endif; ?>/>` It will show the php if as text ...

Comment: My bad see my edit @Ronny

Comment: the mobile is still listed '<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.mystore.nl/kids.html?___store=nl&amp;___from_store=nl"hreflang="nl"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.mystore.co.uk/kids.html?SID=6e3ktucv940h2qvs0rkddl50k6&amp;___store=en&amp;___from_store=nl"hreflang="en"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.mystore.de/kids.html?SID=6e3ktucv940h2qvs0rkddl50k6&amp;___store=de&amp;___from_store=nl"hreflang="de"/>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.mystore.nl/kids.html?___store=mobile&amp;___from_store=nl"/>'

Comment: @Ronny what about now ?

Comment: That solved it!